# Help with Control+m shortcut

Tags: mac-os-x, keyboard

I am attempting to create a keyboard menu item shortcut using control + m.  I have been successful at doing this however, I'm running into problems with this particular shortcut as it works about half the time.

Upon further inspection I discovered that control+m seems to already have an assignment.  It insert a new row in a matrix.  I don't see control+m in the keyeventtranslations.tr file and there is no mention of this shortcut anywhere in wolfram documentation.  As far as I can tell, it should be unassigned.  Did I create this accidentally in the past?  Can you verify on your mac if this shortcut is active on your machine?

If I did pick it up somewhere, do you have any suggestions on where I can look for this so I can change or delete it?  It's not in my keyeventtranslation.tr file and I don't see it in my init.m file.  I have tried restarting mathematica.  No luck.

Comment: I have also disabled ALL shortcuts in my OS X system preferences, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Did you also check your MenuSetup.tr?

Comment: I've never modified it so I didn't check it.  But I'll check now.  Do you have any assignment when pressing control+m?

Comment: No, but for control+shift+m. (I'm on Windows.)

Comment: I checked menusetup.tr.  Nothing there either.  I see.  Does that shortcut give you an added row in a  matrix?

Comment: No, it's the keyboard shortcut for the menu entry Cell►Merge Cells. Control+Enter creates additional rows.

Comment: I see.  The merge cells shortcut is slightly different on a Mac.  The create additional rows shortcut is the same.  Control+enter does it.  This is why I'm surprised control+m does the same thing.  I think I may have created it accidentally somehow, or it's a bug in Mathrmatica.